# Visual Studio 2012 Portable Class Library reference error

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 RC to create Silverlight LOB apps. I'm getting a build error every time I add a reference to a portable class library.

The "ResolveAssemblyReference" task failed unexpectedly. 
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.WinMDFoldersExInfo' from assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I nutted out that Silverlight projects can reference the PCL and everything works as expected, but any .NET projects (class libraries, web applications, etc) objects. I tried changed the target platform from .NET 4.5 to 4, with no difference. As soon as I remove the reference to the PCL, the error goes away.

The PCL's target frameworks are:
.NET for Metro style apps
.NET Framework 4.5
Silverlight 4 and higher
Windows Phone 7 and higher

I've tried changing the target frameworks, but it doesn't seem to help. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: 2012 RTM has been available for months, so discussing RC bits is of no value right now.

Comment: @LexLi Same problem with VS 2010 Ultimate, that's all I've got installed at the moment.

Comment: Do you mean you can reproduce this issue on another machine with Visual Studio 2012 RTM? If not, you'd better try that first. I don't trust that you can upgrade from RC to RTM.

Comment: Yep, thank you very much, that sorted the problem.